# Unanswered queue

Tags: support, bug

Why is this topic in the unanswered queue?

[Why is a "Czech bed roll" called this? History, uses?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5637/why-is-a-czech-bed-roll-called-this-history-uses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer has zero score. Questions are considered "answered" when they have <s>an accepted answer or</s> an answer with a score > 0.

Comment: One clarification — A user "accepting" an answer will not remove it from the 'unanswered' page. It contains all questions with no upvoted answers (accepted or not).